# Different path for grid move

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, dynamic-programming

> Given a m * n grids, and one is allowed to move up or right, find the different number of paths between two grid points.

My major idea is, if move `r` steps right, `u` steps up, we can find (1) solutions for `r-1` steps right and u steps up, then combine with one final right step (2) solutions for `r` steps right and `u-1` steps up, then combine with one final up step.

I use a dynamic programming matrix `dp` to track number of path. For example, `dp[i][j]` means if we move `i` steps right and `j` steps up.

Any advice on code bugs, smarter ideas in terms of algorithm time complexity or code style advice is appreciated.

```
def move_right_up_count(rights, ups):
    dp = [[0] * (ups+1) for _ in range(1+rights)]
    for i in range(1,rights+1):
        dp[i][0] = 1
    for j in range(1, ups+1):
        dp[0][j] = 1
    for i in range(1, rights+1):
        for j in range(1, ups+1):
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] + dp[i][j-1]
    return dp[-1][-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print move_right_up_count(2,3)
```

Comment: Smarter algorithm: prove that the answer is equal to (u+r)!/(u!r!)

Comment: @RazimanT.V., I agree with you the direct count method is a very cool idea, vote up. For my original code and question, do you have any comemnts?

Comment: It's pretty good, you could modify it to use a 2*n array instead of m*n though

Comment: @RazimanT.V., nice idea and vote up. I make improvements based on your new idea and any advice is appreciated. Refer here => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153012/different-path-for-grid-move-part-2

Comment: I added a little bit more content you may find interesting.

Answer (score 4):

**PEP 8**

PEP 8 complains about this line:

```
for i in range(1,rights+1):
```

You should have a single space after the comma and before `rights+1`:

```
for i in range(1, rights+1):
```

**Straight to business**

Taking on the advice of [Raziman T. V.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/67726/raziman-t-v): you are allowed to move \$u\$ steps up and \$r\$ steps right. Now denote a move upward by `u` and the move to the right by `r`. The total number of moves is \$u + r\$. Next, every valid path is a string of length \$u + r\$ containing \$u\$ characters `u` and \$r\$ characters `r`; clearly, any such string denotes a valid path.

Now, you can permute a string of length \$u + r\$ in \$(u + r)!\$ ways. However, since all `u`s (respectively, `r`s) are equal, you divide \$(u + r)!\$ by \$u!r!\$ since there is \$u!\$ ways to permute the subsequence of \$u\$ characters `u` and each of them are equal; same for characters `r`.

The above leads to

$$\frac{(u + r)!}{u!r!},$$

and, finally, to the code

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)


def count_paths(r, u):
    return factorial(r + u) / factorial(r) / factorial(u)
```

**Edit**

You can optimize the above a little bit:

```
def count_paths_v2(r, u):
    min_ru, max_ru = min(r, u), max(r, u)
    value = 1
    for i in range(max_ru + 1, r + u + 1):
        value *= i
    return value / factorial(min_ru)
```

`count_paths` performs \$(u + r) + u + r\$ steps, and `count_paths_v2` only \$\min(u, r) + (r + u) - \max(r, u).\$

**Cleaning a bit**

What comes to your version, you can write it a little bit more succintly:

```
def move_right_up_count(rights, ups):
    grid = [[1 for _ in range(rights + 1)] for _ in range(ups + 1)]
    for y in range(1, ups + 1):
        for x in range(1, rights + 1):
            grid[y][x] = grid[y - 1][x] + grid[y][x - 1]
    return grid[-1][-1]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks coderodde, I agree with you the direct count method is a very cool idea, vote up. For my original code and question, do you have any comemnts?

Comment: @LinMa No, unfortunately that's all I can say. :(

Comment: It is ok, and I have make a new post for some new ideas, if you have any advice on it, it will be great. :)

Refer to => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153012/different-path-for-grid-move-part-2