# Different path for grid move (part 2)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

This is a continued discussion from ([Different path for grid move](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152837/different-path-for-grid-move)) to optimize for space complexity, and since it is new code and I make a new post.

> Given a m * n grids, and one is allowed to move up or right, find the different number of paths between two grid points.

My major idea is, if move `r` steps right, `u` steps up, we can find (1) solutions for `r-1` steps right and u steps up, then combine with one final right step (2) solutions for `r` steps right and `u-1` steps up, then combine with one final up step.

I use a dynamic programming method to track count in `r-1` steps (using `pre_row`) and `r` steps (using `cur_row`). Here is my code and any advice on code bugs, performance improvements in terms of time complexity, or code style issues are appreciated.

**Source code in Python 2.7**,

```
def grid_move(rights, ups):
    pre_row = []
    pre_row.append(0)
    # initialize for zero right and up only
    for i in range(1, ups+1):
        pre_row.append(1)
    cur_row = []
    for r in range(1, rights+1):
        for u in range(0, ups+1):
            if u > 0:
                cur_row.append(pre_row[u] + cur_row[-1])
            else:
                cur_row.append(1)
        pre_row = cur_row

    return cur_row[-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print grid_move(2,3)
```

Comment: Why do you append 0 first? It should be 1.

Comment: @RazimanT.V., zero up ad zero rights, there is no solution, why should be 1?

Comment: There is exactly one way to do nothing. nC0 is 1 not 0.

Answer (score 4):

The code has a bug: Since you are appending elements, you have to make sure that the array is empty in the beginning. So the `cur_row = []` command should be inside the loop.

Also, the number of ways to reach origin from origin is 1. Hence `pre_row` should have all elements 1 initially. This means that you can just do `pre_row = [1] * (ups+1)` instead of appending.

Next problem is kind of aesthetic. You are building `cur_row` at each step and turning `pre_row` into it in the end. Then it makes sense to fill `cur_row` before the loop as well, and that will make sure that the code also works for `rights == 0`.

Once we do these, there is no longer the need to append to `cur_row` inside the loop. We are sure that the list has the correct size so we can just assign elements.

Finally just remove the `if` inside the loop.

Combining these we have

```
def grid_move(rights, ups):
    cur_row = [1] * (ups+1)
    for r in range(1, rights+1):
        pre_row = cur_row
        cur_row[0] = 1
        for u in range(1, ups+1):
                cur_row[u] = pre_row[u] + cur_row[u-1]

    return cur_row[-1]
```

These should make the code more readable and efficient, and make the recurrence relation clear.

Comment: Exercise: Can you modify the code to not require pre_row at all?

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why `the number of ways to reach origin from origin is 1`? I think zero up and zero rights have no solution, so should be zero (zero means no solution).

Comment: BTW, Raziman, I find even if after I initialize first element from `0` to `1`, my code returns `6` for `grid_move(4,2)`, however your code returns `15`, your code returns the right answer. But I am confused since we have almost identify code? What is wrong with my code for `grid_move(4,2)` case?

Comment: BTW, Raziman, as a follow-up, I improved code by using only `cur`, I post my code here, and your advice is highly appreciated, always. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153102/different-path-for-grid-move-part-3

Comment: Changing 0 to 1 is not enough, you also need to reset cur in the beginning of the loop if you are appending.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have a bug: `grid_move(4, 2)` is 6, when the right answer should be

$$
\frac{(4 + 2)!}{4! 2!} = \frac{6!}{4!2!} = \frac{6 \times 5}{2} = 15.
$$

Comment: You are right, coderodde, vote up, but what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified to a closed form, with a few observations.

For an n * m grid, where you start in the lower left corner and have a choice between "move right" and "move up", you will always execute exactly n + m - 2 moves. Of these, n-1 will be "right" and "m-1" will be up.

This is, as it happens, the same as "pick n-1 combinations from (n + m - 2)" elements and should, for low "n and m" be solvable in constant space (if n and m get sufficiently large, they could end up overflowing fixed-size integers and require bignums). In the code below, `n - 1` is `rights` and `m - 1` is `ups`. Depending on the exact Python version, you may need to change `range` to `xrange` to get constant space.

Example Python code:

```
def grid_mode(rights, ups):
    acc = 1
    low = min(rights, ups)
    high = max(rights, ups)
    for i in range(high, (high + low)):
        # We get high, high+1, ... high+low-1 from the range
        # We actually want the product of high+1, ..., high+low
        acc *= i + 1

    for i in range(2, low+1):
        acc //= i

    return acc
```

Comment: @Graipher You're correct, I should've used `//=` to signal integerness. Due to the numbers, the result will always be an integer, so both `/=` and `//=` should end up with the same result in any Python version that supports `//`.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, what do you mean "pick n-1 combinations from (n + m - 2)" elements ", I think it should be permutation other than combination, since order matters, and also it should be permutation of `(n+m-2)` elements (with repetitive `n-1` for rights, and `m-1` for ups)?

Comment: BTW, for your code `acc *= i + 1`, does it have any logical meaning? Or it is just simply a way to calculate combination formula?

Comment: @LinMa It's just easier to do `i+1` than `range(high+1, high + low + 1)`. But it is just the combination formula, yes.