# Different path for grid move (part 3)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

This is a continued discussion from ([Different path for grid move (part 2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153012/different-path-for-grid-move-part-2)) to optimize for space complexity (using only `cur` list, other than a `cur` and another `pre` lists), and since it is new code and I make a new post.

> Given a m * n grids, and one is allowed to move up or right, find the different number of paths between two grid points.

My major idea is, if move `r` steps right, `u` steps up, we can find (1) solutions for `r-1` steps right and u steps up, then combine with one final right step (2) solutions for `r` steps right and `u-1` steps up, then combine with one final up step.

**Source code in Python 2.7**,

```
def grid_move_v2(rights, ups):
    cur = [1] * (ups + 1)
    for r in range(1, rights+1):
        for u in range(1, ups+1):
            cur[u] = cur[u] + cur[u-1]
    return cur[-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print grid_move_v2(2,3)
    print grid_move_v2(4,2)
```

Comment: That is correct. I am not very familiar with Python style rules, so perhaps someone else can help you with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just [use coderodde's formula](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153014):

$$\frac{(a + b)!}{a!b!}$$

Assuming \$a \le b\$, you can reduce the amount of numbers you need to multiply by.
Using:

$$\frac{\Pi_{i = 1 + b}^{i \le a + b}i}{a!}$$

And so you can get \$O(a)\$, rather than \$O(a + b)\$ or \$O(ab)\$ code:

```
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import mul

product = partial(reduce, mul)

def grid_move(a, b):
    a, b = sorted([a, b])
    return product(range(1 + b, a + b + 1)) / product(range(2, a + 1), 1)
```

Comment: finally! I ruined half of my working day today just because I was trying to get this formula to answer, I was 100% sure that there is a pure math way to calculate this.

Comment: Nice idea Peilonrayz, mark your reply as answer to benefit other people who has similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Since you never use `r` you can shift it down by one and call it `_` (the customary unused variable in Python).

```
def grid_move_v2(rights, ups):
    cur = [1] * (ups + 1)
    for _ in range(rights):
        for u in range(1, ups+1):
            cur[u] = cur[u] + cur[u-1]
    return cur[-1]
```

Comment: Looks nice! It is more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
    for u in range(1, ups+1):
        cur[u] = cur[u] + cur[u-1]
```

is just an accumulation loop. Python 3 has the [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function to perform it efficiently, but you can borrow the code from there if you want to stay with Python 2: it will name things and make the code more readable:

```
def accumulate(iterable):
    """Return running totals"""
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = total + element
        yield total


def grid_move_v2(rights, ups):
    cur = [1] * (ups + 1)
    for _ in range(rights):
        cur = accumulate(cur)
    return list(cur)[-1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print grid_move_v2(2,3)
    print grid_move_v2(4,2)
```

(I also used the improvement proposed by [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153110/84718))

Comment: Nice answer, and vote up!